# Error while using SimplePHPUnit Package

Tags: phpunit, sublimetext3

I am currently using the following package from github for my sublime text 3 and getting error message

Github package https://github.com/pr0ggy/SimplePHPUnit-for-Sublime-Text

Error This version of PHPUnit requires PHP 5.6; using the latest version of PHP is highly recommended.
[Finished in 0.1s]

```
PHP 7.0.2 (cli) (built: Jan  8 2016 10:14:20) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2015 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.0.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2015 Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v7.0.6-dev, Copyright (c) 1999-2015, by Zend Technologies
[  4:01PM ]  [ manshu@Himanshus-MacBook-Pro:~(ruby-2.3.0) ]
```

Comment: What's your question? The plugin requires PHP 5.6, and you're using PHP 7.

Comment: Question was to fix that error. I realized to install phpunit globally. @MattDMo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to installed phpunit again and it worked with CHMOD755 on the phar file.